Beach Flip Flops Outside Backpack
I'll be flying to Menorca from Portugal with just a backpack.
My question is, can I tie, with some wire, my beach flip flops to outside of the backpack, and travel with them there? I will travel with Vueling.
Thanks.

Probably yes, but what happens if for some reason airline staff tell you the backpack has to be checked in?

If the backpack with the flip flops locked on are within the allowed dimensions, you can, But the airline will probably claim less responsibility for them if "packed" that way, and they more exposed to damage/loss.

@Traveller, thats what im afraid, in normal conditions the backpack will travel with me, but i guess i never know what they will say when boarding. Im asking cause i see many people travelling with sneakers tied to the backpack.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity, yes, its a small backpack, thats why i want to save some space with the flip flops outside. Thanks for the answer.

I guess one question to ask yourself would be, how would you feel when hit in the face by someone else's flip-flops or sneakers tied to their backpack

Depending on the security arrangements (i.e. is scanning far away from checkin and boarding) you could stick the flipflops up your shirt to board. I assume they're fairly flat.

I carry a small nylon grocery bag, not the big bulky ones the stores sell you, but one that folds up small -- you could fit it in your mouth, though I don't recommend that. You can keep it in a pocket of your backpack or clip it on, and it will come in handy many times:

when you need to carry slightly more than usual, such as when you've just been shopping
when you need to carry something that is a little dirty and you don't want it in your backpack (I recommend using the bag inside out in this case, to keep the inside clean)
when you have something wet (a bathing suit, or just-done laundry) and you don't want to get the things in the backpack wet
when you want to take just a subset of your possessions with you: you can leave the backpack and take the open bag, or vice versa
when you are asked to put the backpack somewhere less accessible, but want access to some of your things, you can keep them with you in the bag. This could be checking the backpack or putting in the overhead bin, for example.

When it's in use, you can either carry it in your hands, or in some cases tie the handles to a loop or strap on your backpack. This gives you flexibility to deal with not only your flip flops but many other circumstances likely to arise on a trip like this.
Here's an example from Amazon, I'm not recommending this brand or seller but just demonstrating how small they are, how much they hold, and how cheap they are ($15 Cdn for 6 which is a lifetime supply and will let you take an extra or two that you might give away or otherwise find good use for.)

Years ago I worked in Russia for 6 months, and always carried around bags like that because you could never guarantee that you'd find an item in a store a second time.  We called "perhaps" bags, as in "perhaps I might find something I need today"

Our family name for them is "FirstName bags" where FirstName is a family member very in tune with trends and such, with connections in Japan, who gave us all one a decade or more ago. Over time I've discovered how incredibly useful they are to just always have with you. You end up being glad of them!

@KateGregory i think i'll try to use one of these bags. Thanks for the help.

You can, but it's a bad idea, they're likely to fall off or break, especially if you need to check your bag for some reason.
Is there really no space in the backpack for the flipflops?  Alternatively, you could put both backpack and flipflops in a plastic bag.
